# Site redirects to install.php file over and over again after installation of Drupal

Tags: installation

I installed Drupal-7.x-2.0-alpha5-core in my localhost and installation completed successfully but i can't go into the site after installation. it directs me to the install.php file over and over again.Is there anything i can do to fix this ?

Comment: Did you check the database settings in "settings.php" file?

Comment: Yes, this happens when Drupal can't connect to the database, e.g invalid database login credentials or unreadable settings.php file.

Comment: My experience was that:
1. the settings.php file had to be changed in two ways: - The value 'update free access' temporarely set to 'TRUE' and - chmod of the settings.php should not be 400, I changed it to 644. 2. In .htaccess if you had drupal installed in a subdirectory, look for 'RewriteBase' and change it to RewriteBase / Now it works.....

Comment: Just recently happened to a colleague at work; there was no settings.php file. Check to ensure the settings.php file is present at [your-site-root]/sites/default/files. If this does not work let us know, whats your operating system? and how did you install Drupal, via git, drush or just download from a source?

Comment: I found that running http://example.com/update.php fixed this issue for me.